# gatling inject user vs jmeter thread group

Tags: performance, testing, jmeter, gatling

How do I match the jmeter thread group with gatling simulation setup inject user?
lets say i'm trying to run 100 vuser for duration of 1 hour which loops forever during the test and ramps down after 1 hour without any thinktime for testing.
I'm running tests on both jmeter and galting but they both have different TPS. I'm getting a lot of requests per min in jmeter but only few in gatling.
Is there a way to make sure gatling tool vusers are also looping forever during the test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could probably emulate the load generated by the JMeter's thread group with the same number of gatling users doing `forever` loop.

The question is why would you really want to do that as the Gatling's model is more realistic than JMeter's? You still won't have 100% same baseline as gatling is built on a different concurrency principles.

Comment: thx. I'm new to gatling so didnt know about loop. I was able to run test as per my need using loop. I used .during(duration) for this purpose . .during(duration, counterName, exitASAP) {
  myChain
}